# Which password is required to connect to database in the bitnami osqa virtual machine?

Tags: postgresql, psql, bitnami

I'm using the virtual machine Bitnami provides for osqa:

https://bitnami.com/stack/osqa

I want to connect to the database using the psql command.

```
psql bitnami_osqa
```

But when I do so, it asks me for a password. I have tried 'bitnami' and the password I defined for the OS user. I receive the following message:

```
psql.bin: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "bitnami"
```

The app connection to the database is working correctly. The database config used by the application (extracted from the **settings_local.py**) is :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'bitnami_osqa',
        'USER': 'bn_osqa',
        'PASSWORD': '93bcbf303934',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600,
    }
}
```

What should I enter to connect? Or am I not using the psql command right?

Answer (score 0):

The settings.py is telling you all the information that you need to connect the database.

Only read the help of psql to know which flags you need to use:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U bn_osqa -d bitnami_osqa
```

As the host and the port are the default you don't have to write it in the command, so it can be more concise:

```
psql -U bn_osqa -d bitnami_osqa
```

The password in you case is: `93bcbf303934`